# rsyslog unable to identify docker container id as hostname from log4j 1x

Tags: docker, log4j, rsyslog

My log4j 1x version is sending logs from a docker container to syslog server. In my rsyslog.conf I am storing these logs under /var/log/rsyslog/appname/%hostname% .

Ideally if I am sending the logs from my log4j1x docker container, rsyslog should identify the container id as %hostname% but it identifies the underlying server as hostname. This is not the case when my nginx docker container sends logs to rsyslog. It correct identifies the container id as hostname.

Can someone assist please?